# AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'middleware_stack

Tags: web3.py

- web3.py version: `5.0.1`,  Python: `3.6.3`

Following code was working on `web3==4.9.2`, which does not work for the `web3==5.0.1`. I am getting following error:

```bash
web3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'middleware_stack'
```

---

Example piece of code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from web3 import Web3
from web3.providers.rpc import HTTPProvider
from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider

web3 = Web3(IPCProvider('/private/geth.ipc'))
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
# inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
web3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, 'shh')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Web3.middleware_onion.add(middleware, name=None)`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#Web3.middleware_onion.add)

Replacing `web3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)` with `web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)` fixed the problem.