# How to get gas estimate and gas price on Polygon Mumbai Chain using web3.py?

Tags: web3.py, gas-price, polygon, gas-estimate

I have deployed a contract on `Goerli` test net and used the following to get the estimated gas and current gas price.

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)    

contract_transaction_struct = contract.functions.addRow(_var1, _var2,...).buildTransaction()

gas_estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas(contract_transaction_struct)

current_gas_price = web3.eth.gasPrice
```

and it worked fine.

Now, I deployed the same contract on `Polygom Mumbai` test net.

Getting the following error

> ```
> contract_transaction_struct = contract.functions.addRow(_root, _length, _secret, _file_extension, _storage_peers, _backup_peers, _upload_endpoint ).buildTransaction()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/_utils/decorators.py",
> ```
>
> line 51, in wrapper
> return to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1112,
> in buildTransaction
> return self.build_transaction(transaction)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1107,
> in build_transaction
> **self.kwargs   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1672,
> in build_transaction_for_function
> prepared_transaction = fill_transaction_defaults(web3, prepared_transaction)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 249, in
> cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py",
> line 114, in fill_transaction_defaults
> default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py",
> line 64, in 
> web3.eth.max_priority_fee + (2 * web3.eth.get_block('latest')['baseFeePerGas'])   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 690, in
> get_block
> return self._get_block(block_identifier, full_transactions)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 60, in
> caller
> null_result_formatters)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 197, in
> request_blocking
> response = self._make_request(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 150, in
> _make_request
> return request_func(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py",
> line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/gas_price_strategy.py",
> line 90, in middleware
> return make_request(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py",
> line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/attrdict.py",
> line 33, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py",
> line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py",
> line 96, in middleware
> return _apply_response_formatters(method=method, response=response, **formatters)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py",
> line 51, in _apply_response_formatters
> return _format_response("result", result_formatters[method])   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py",
> line 47, in _format_response
> response, response_type, method_response_formatter(appropriate_response)   File
> "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/applicators.py",
> line 72, in apply_formatter_if
> return formatter(value)   File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 249, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.**call**   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line
> 45, in inner
> return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/applicators.py",
> line 84, in apply_formatters_to_dict
> yield key, formatterskey   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/validation.py",
> line 79, in _check_extradata_length
> len(result), MAX_EXTRADATA_LENGTH, result web3.exceptions.ExtraDataLengthError: The field extraData is 97 bytes,
> but should be 32. It is quite likely that you are connected to a POA
> chain. Refer to
> http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority
> for more details. The full extraData is:
> HexBytes('0xd682030283626f7288676f312e31392e34856c696e7578000000000000000000ed945a3cb9bde3dd4c588e8710adb72e1668e8933f5c6d840d37e615658cbd741944e15deda7e4905984ae8c041574eee5b2daf32b7166c9457c6a71525a705b00')

I did some research and added

```
w3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
```

Got error

> ```
> w3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0) AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'middleware_stack'
> ```

I am using Web3.py `version 5.31.3`.

Anyways, I again chaged to

```
w3.add_middleware(geth_poa_middleware)
```

Getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Edit: As suggested by Mikko Ohtamaa..yes was doing it wrong. the correct way to use `geth_poa_middleware` is

```
web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
```

As suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74044/attributeerror-web3-object-has-no-attribute-middleware-stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default web3.py APIs need a special support for some blockchains, as they insert extra data in their transactions.

Your suggestion how to solve the problem is correct and should work. If it does not work then you are doing it incorrectly and you need to debug your code e.g. using Python debuggers to figure out why this middleware is not being activated for your application.

Comment: Ok. let me try.

Comment: Yes...I was doing it wrong. Updating the post with the answer.